# How to create monthly running sum when some months have no records

Tags: sql, postgresql

The goal is to graph the total volume of created orders over time in a monthly digest

```
WITH monthly_sums AS (
  SELECT
    date_trunc('month', created_at) AS month,
    sum(count(created_at)) OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc('month', created_at)) AS sum
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY date_trunc('month', created_at)
)
SELECT
  to_char(date_range.month, 'Month') AS month,
  COALESCE(monthly_sums.sum, 0) AS total
FROM generate_series('2014-10-01'::date, CURRENT_DATE, '1 month') date_range(month)
LEFT OUTER JOIN monthly_sums
ON monthly_sums.month = date_range.month;
```

Which returns:

```
   month   | total
-----------+-------
 October   |     0
 November  |     0
 December  |     0
 January   |     1
 February  |     0     <-- should be 1
 March     |     3
(6 rows)
```

selecting from monthly_sums returns:

```
        month        | sum
---------------------+-----
 2015-01-01 00:00:00 |   1
                     |         <-- no records created in February
 2015-03-01 00:00:00 |   3
                     |   3
(3 rows)
```

The problem is there were no orders in February so the total is coalesced into 0.  How can I alter or rethink this query in order to get the desired result?

Comment: You need to do the running sum in the outer query, not inside the CTE

Comment: how could that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unfamiliar with the postgresql syntax for this construct, but the general pattern across all SQL engines for implementing this type of operation efficiently is always the following:

1. Aggregate by month;
2. Left join from the full set of desired periods to the aggregates in (1), coalescing absent sums to zero;
3. Perform the running summation by period.

Use either CTE's or subqueries to build 1, 2, and 3 successively.

Answer (score 0):

following Pieter's answer, this altered query gives the correct result

```sql
WITH monthly_counts AS (
  SELECT
    date_trunc('month', created_at) AS month,
    count(created_at) AS count
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY date_trunc('month', created_at)
)
SELECT
  to_char(sq.month, 'Month') AS month,
  sum(sq.count) OVER (ORDER BY sq.month)
FROM
  (SELECT
    date_range.month,
    COALESCE(monthly_counts.count, 0) AS count
  FROM generate_series('2014-10-01'::date, CURRENT_DATE, '1 month') date_range(month)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN monthly_counts
  ON monthly_counts.month = date_range.month) AS sq;
```